# how to retain the template view in angular js routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am writing a web app similar to dropbox and gdrive, i fetch ids of file based on that it will be able to navigate from page to page, folder to folder, e.g /abc to abc/abc... All i need to do it from client side. I made it simple using AngularJS Routing(ui-router).
Here is my code

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard.sync.root', {
  url: "/*path",
    templateUrl: "root.html",})
here user can navigate like http://myweb/dashboard/sync/root/abc or http://myweb/dashboard/sync/root/abc/.../../
```

while traversing from page to page the root.html(template) goes on changing.
Problem here is when I traverse back and forth, it doesnt store previous view. when i click back and forward button in browser. Any Solution Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 different files to maintain your app:

```
header.html
body.html
footer.html
```

And use ng-view in body to include using your routes.